# Why Spring Integration management configuration doesn't work by default?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am investigating the new Spring Integration benefit - integration management configuration, in the basis of java docs this one is provided with 4.2 release.

I've written simple java based context.

```java
/**
 * @author Eugene Stepanenkov
 */
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@EnableIntegrationManagement
@IntegrationComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.stepsoft.study.flow",
        "com.stepsoft.study.configuration.flow",
        "com.stepsoft.study.flow.messaging"
})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.stepsoft.study.flow",
        "com.stepsoft.study.configuration.flow",
        "com.stepsoft.study.flow.messaging"
})
@Import({
        DataContext.class,
        ImportFlowContext.class
})
@PropertySource("classpath:flow.properties")
public class FlowContext {

    @Value("${flow.defaultPoller.fixedDelay}")
    private int fixedDelay;

    @Value("${flow.defaultPoller.maxMessagesPerPoll}")
    private int maxMessagesPerPoll;

    @Bean(name = DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {

        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(fixedDelay, MILLISECONDS));
        pollerMetadata.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll);

        return pollerMetadata;
    }
}
```

When initialization of context is performed I get `IllegalArgumentException enabledCountsPatterns must not be empty`.

I've found this place in sources

```java
    /**
     * Set the array of simple patterns for component names for which message counts will
     * be enabled (defaults to '*').
     * Enables message counting (`sendCount`, `errorCount`, `receiveCount`)
     * for those components that support counters (channels, message handlers, etc).
     * This is the initial setting only, individual components can have counts
     * enabled/disabled at runtime. May be overridden by an entry in
     * {@link #setEnabledStatsPatterns(String[]) enabledStatsPatterns} which is additional
     * functionality over simple counts. If a pattern starts with `!`, counts are disabled
     * for matches. For components that match multiple patterns, the first pattern wins.
     * Disabling counts at runtime also disables stats.
     * @param enabledCountsPatterns the patterns.
     */
    public void setEnabledCountsPatterns(String[] enabledCountsPatterns) {
        Assert.notEmpty(enabledCountsPatterns, "enabledCountsPatterns must not be empty");
        this.enabledCountsPatterns = Arrays.copyOf(enabledCountsPatterns, enabledCountsPatterns.length);
    }
```

As far as I understand this property is got from annotation `EnableIntegrationManagement`

```java
    /**
     * A list of simple patterns for component names for which message counts will be
     * enabled (defaults to '*'). Enables message
     * counting (`sendCount`, `errorCount`, `receiveCount`) for those components that
     * support counters (channels, message handlers, etc). This is the initial setting
     * only, individual components can have counts enabled/disabled at runtime. May be
     * overridden by an entry in {@link #statsEnabled() statsEnabled} which is additional
     * functionality over simple counts. If a pattern starts with `!`, counts are disabled
     * for matches. For components that match multiple patterns, the first pattern wins.
     * Disabling counts at runtime also disables stats.
     * Defaults to no components, unless JMX is enabled in which case, defaults to all
     * components. Overrides {@link #defaultCountsEnabled()} for matching bean names.
     * @return the patterns.
     */
    String[] countsEnabled() default "";
```

But at the same time:

```java
   /**
    * The default setting for enabling counts when a bean name is not matched by
    * {@link #countsEnabled() countsEnabled}.
    * @return the value; false by default, or true when JMX is enabled.
    */
   String defaultCountsEnabled() default "false";
```

So I have two misunderstandings:

1. Why in java docs written - `(defaults to '*')`, but default value is `''` as presented in annotation?
2. Why is there no logic to check if `defaultCountsEnabled` is true then check `countsEnabled` property?

**P.S.** I don't like I need to provide default value by myself using custom annotation or setting those properties in existing one. Even more: in the basis of the sources the same think is related to property `defaultStatsEnabled` in a couple with `statsEnabled`. Also in java docs related to `metricsFactory` described `The DefaultMetricsFactory is used if omitted` but it seems I will also get an error and most likely it will be `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3826).

It is fixed on master (4.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in the repo.spring.io/snapshots repo); it will be fixed in the 4.2.1.RELEASE which we plan to release next week.

We failed to add a test for the default annotation (no attributes); otherwise we'd have discovered it earlier.